# Unity: CustomDrawers for ScriptableObjects?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying ot make a custom drawer for a simple Aspect:ScriptableObject. I can get everything to work for the Aspect class as long as it's a generic class, but as soon as it's a ScriptableObject everything breaks. Specifically:

```
EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property.FindPropertyRelative("AspectName"),
                        new GUIContent("Aspect:"));
```

but the findPropRel is null. using property.serializedObject returns the parent object the Aspect is on, not the Aspect. I can't even hack together a solution that uses that since I don't know which aspect it is.

Is there no way to create a customDrawer for scriptableObjects or Monobehaviours? I can't imagine Unity would make CustomDrawers that can't even be used with the most common Unity class.

And no, a customEditor really doesn't work in this situation. I'd have to make dozens for completely unrelated classes just to draw the aspect.

Answer (score 3):

I am also having the same problem. I've reached a kind of trick to get properties from a **ScriptableObject**, but not using *FindPropertyRelative*, wich does not work for **ScriptableObject** but works well for plain objects.

Also using MonoBehaviour will not work if you plan to instantiate the class in another **MonoBehavior** class, as **MonoBehavior** classes can only be added as components to **GameObject**(s). You cannot create it using ***new***, or Unity will complain.

I have to tell you, that yet I don't think my solution is really valid because I am not sure if it works well on prefabs, but that could be maybe because I am trying to save some scene references on the prefab and that seems that cannot be done in Unity.

Well. Stop speech. That is what I do:

Supposing your **ScriptabeObject** you want to access is of class MySOClass.

```
public override void OnGUI(Rect pos, SerializedProperty prop, GUIContent label) {
    // Make a new serialized object for your property that is a class that inherits
    // from ScriptableObject
    SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(prop.objectReferenceValue as MySOClass);
    SerializedProperty propSP = serializedObject.FindProperty("prop");

    if (propSP != null) {
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(propSP , true);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) {
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

The fact that I test nulliness of propSP , is because if the actual value of prop is null, Serialized property returned will be also null.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I'll try playing around with this design and return if I stumble upon any issues.

Comment: Not sure when this broke but `prop.objectReferenceValue` always returns `null` for ScriptableObjects.